# How to run a specific Gitlab job from another Gitlab pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, jobs

Is there any way to extend and run only a specific job from another pipeline in my current pipeline without copy-pasting it?

For example I have two pipelines:
1. build -> code_check -> auto_test -> deploy
2. auto_test* -> report

I want to execute pipeline 2 where auto_test* executes on another runner while keeping the job's keys exactly as they are in pipeline 1 (except for "tags" which I add in the job to be able to use another runner).

I have a process restriction that I can't change anything in pipeline 1 config so I need a way to execute only a specific job.

I have tried to do that through include .gitlab-ci.yaml+extends:. It somewhat works but pipeline 2 will have all jobs from both pipelines and it is not what I would like to see.

The most straightforward way would be just to copy on each update auto_test job specification from pipeline 1 into my gitlab-ci YAML of pipeline 2 and adding tags: ["MyRunner"] but I hoped there is a built-in way to do that.

Comment: You could extract common part of pipeline to some template and import it in both pipelines. But that will require to change pipeline 1.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that's the trickiest part unfortunately. Seems like I need to stick to a solution with scripted import of CI-configuration from pipeline 1, modifying it the way we need it and building a configuration for pipeline 2.